Can a Buddhist join the army?
Can the Buddhist lay person join the army of their own country?
What is the Buddhist view on this?
Is defending defenceless and protecting weak by joining to the military not allowed in Buddhism?
And, what's the karmic (karma) difference of

non-military person hurting (in fighting) someone else

vs

military person hurting (in fighting) someone else?

So, if joining the army is not an option, how should they defend their country?

Is there such a thing as a just and righteous war? When the trigger is pulled, there is only suffering and pain. Should one’s life, the lives of one’s beloved, the sanctity of one’s homeland be defended against a tyrant (such as the one who started a war in Europe)? Unfortunately, as a Buddhist, I don’t have an answer.

Interesting question.
I’m Sri Lankan. My parents were Buddhist, so I was raised Buddhist too. We had a civil war, and one of my close friends even died in the war as a soldier when he was 20 years old. Based on this background, I’ll try to explain another angle where you might find an answer to your question.
When we label someone as a Buddhist, what is that based on? I know Christians have to register themselves with a church (and it’s similar for most religions). But in Buddhism, there’s nothing like that—no formal activities like baptism, etc. So, I used to wonder, how did I become a Buddhist? The simple answer that came to mind was because my parents were Buddhist.
But then, how does one become a real Buddhist?
People say Buddhism is a way of living, and they also say it’s a journey. So, by living in a Buddhist society or reading the Dhamma, can I become a Buddhist?
We know about Devadatta, a monk who lived during the Buddha’s time. But was he a real Buddhist? After all, he even planned to kill the Buddha.
So, just by being a monk or labeling ourselves, we don’t necessarily become real Buddhists (no offense to anyone). But then, how do we become true Buddhists? This is why it’s important to study and understand the Buddha’s teachings. However, there are so many versions of these teachings now, and what we find on the internet or in books might not always be accurate.
Anyway in Buddha's preaching its clearly says
The solaces show that the reason for a virtuous life does not necessarily depend on belief in rebirth or retribution, but on mental well-being acquired through the overcoming of greed, hate, and delusion.
Greed, hate, and delusion are all things related to the mind. So, to be a true Buddhist, it’s clear that we need to reach a state of mind where we won’t revert to our previous state. From there, it becomes a step-by-step journey toward enlightenment.
So, back to your question: if a person joins the army to protect “my country,” the word “my” contains the answer to the question itself. However, if a person has to (by the law) join the army to protect the country he live in, it’s a different story.
I hope you see the two sides of this. If someone is becoming a true Buddhist, they will realize that having to join the army (as a forced by the law) is also happening due to causes and conditions. So, instead of conflicting with this reality, they will seek a way out, understanding that if they join the army, they may be required to fire weapons, and someone could get hurt because of that.
The Nibbedhika Sutta says

“Cetanā ‘haṃ bhikkhave kammaṃ vadāmi”

In this context, the Buddha is emphasizing that karma (actions that lead to future consequences) is not just physical action but is primarily based on intention (cetanā).
So a true Buddhist will make sure to protect his thoughts/intentions, because a true Buddhist has a thought process that differs from others (that's a state of nature which happens as a result of realizing the truth (up to some extent) in this world).
When someone becomes a true Buddhist, concepts like “my country” and “army” are clearly understood as human-made constructs. The root cause for attachment to these concepts is often greed or craving, which arises from ignorance or lack of wisdom.
In summary, Buddhism is a way to understand nature and get rid from this sansara chakra, and true Buddhists are aligned with it. And for them concepts like army, country, and even the word “Buddhist” are just fabrications.

Short answer:
It's against Buddha's teaching to kill. Killing is the main focus of armies, their weapons are almost exclusively lethal. Therefore, it is against Buddhist teaching to join an army, because in there a person is trained to kill, takes oaths to follow orders to kill, and punished if he refuses to kill.
How does this reasoning follow from sutras?
Monks, these five trades ought not to be plied by a lay-disciple...
Trade in weapons ... [humans, flesh, intoxicants, poison]

Even providing a weapon is wrong livelihood for a lay person, because it might lead to killing. Surely then, attacking with a weapon is wrong livelihood, because it much more likely leads to killing.
Long answer:

There is no personal karmic difference between military and non-military person hurting/killing somebody, all else being equal. Social status or profession do not free anybody from the law of karma, otherwise it would have been mentioned in sutras - e. g. kill all you want, as long as you are in the army, or a butcher.
If you want to protect a country, you should do it like Gandhi did - non-violently. Gandhi was able to free his country from oppression without waging war. The Roman Empire wasn't able to stop the spread of Christianity with violence, despite pacifism of early Christians. Buddha himself attempted to save his clan (Sakya) from conquest, non-violently, by sitting on the road which the conquering army used.
A person can only be hurt if he has bad karma. I can't find a link but there is a Buddhist story where hunters found a practitioner meditating in a cave, attacked him, but were unable to harm him because he had purified his bad karma. This means that when you are trying to protect somebody, you are trying to prevent their bad karma from coming to fruition.
An ordinary person cannot predict the consequences of killing. People always try to justify killing by saying that they are preventing much greater evil. But in reality, people's predictive abilities are nearly zero, they deceive themselves, and kill with blindness towards consequences. Only bodhisattva would be able to detect a situation where killing is justified, kill without a trace of afflictions in his mind, and endure the karmic blowback without spiraling into more bad actions. You are not a bodhisattva, so don't try it.


The Buddha said he appeared for the benefit of devas & humans. MN 4 says:

Rightly speaking, were it to be said of anyone: ‘A being not subject
to delusion has appeared in the world for the welfare and happiness of
many, out of compassion for the world, for the good, welfare, and
happiness of gods and humans,’ it is of me indeed that rightly
speaking this should be said.
MN 4

The Vinaya repeats this, when saying:

"Go forth, o bhikkhus, for the good of the many, for the happiness of
the many, out of compassion for the world, for the benefit, for the
good, for the happiness of gods and humans. Let not two go by one way.
Preach the doctrine that is beautiful in its beginning, beautiful in
its middle, and beautiful in its ending. Declare the holy life in its
purity, completely both in the spirit and the letter."

The Buddha distinguished the mentality of people in six ways:

Human
Deva
Asura
Ghost
Hell-being
Animal


The fire of lust burns mortals Infatuated by sensual pleasures; The
fire of hate burns malevolent people Who kill other living beings;
The fire of delusion burns the bewildered, Ignorant of the Noble One’s
Dhamma. Being unaware of these three fires, This generation delights
in personal existence.
Unfree from the bonds of Māra They swell the ranks of hell, Existence
in the animal realm, Asura-demons and the sphere of ghosts.
Iti 93

The mentality of humans is not to be soldiers. The suttas say:

When a warrior strives & exerts himself in battle, his mind is already
seized, debased & misdirected by the thought: 'May these beings be
struck down or slaughtered or annihilated or destroyed. May they not
exist.' If others then strike him down & slay him while he is thus
striving & exerting himself in battle, then with the breakup of the
body, after death, he is reborn in the hell called the realm of those
slain in battle. But if he holds such a view as this: 'When a warrior
strives & exerts himself in battle, if others then strike him down &
slay him while he is striving & exerting himself in battle, then with
the breakup of the body, after death, he is reborn in the company of
devas slain in battle,' that is his wrong view. Now, there are two
destinations for a person with wrong view, I tell you: either hell or
the animal womb.
SN 42.3

The Tao Te Ching expresses simply:

There is always an official executioner.
If you try to take his place,
It is like try to be a master carpenter and cutting wood.
If you try to cut wood like a master carpenter,
you will only hurt your hand.
74


Probably not a good idea to quote the dao here, it's mixing doctrines and Buddhism has enough of that to begin with. Tao te ching is philosophy as well, it's polysemic so direct quotes could be mistaken as they can be misunderstood by others. It's essentially a thought exercise. Peoples outcomes from the stanzas may differ. Often do.

While violence and destruction is strongly discouraged in Buddhism, it is ok for a bonafide ruler or government ("wheel-turning monarch") to establish courts of justice, police and armed forces to:

protect and guard the people
ensure peace
ensure that justice prevails

Hence, lay Buddhists can join law enforcement and the armed forces for the purpose stated above.

"What have you heard, Ananda: do the Vajjis duly protect and guard the
arahats, so that those who have not come to the realm yet might do so,
and those who have already come might live there in peace?"
"I have heard, Lord, that they do."
"So long, Ananda, as this is the case, the growth of the Vajjis is to
be expected, not their decline."
DN 16


‘But sire, what are the noble duties of a wheel-turning monarch?’
‘Well then, my dear, relying only on principle—honoring, respecting,
and venerating principle, having principle as your flag, banner, and
authority — provide just protection and security for your court, troops,
aristocrats, vassals, brahmins and householders, people of town and
country, ascetics and brahmins, beasts and birds. Do not let injustice
prevail in the realm. Pay money to the penniless in the realm.
DN 26


However, monks are expected to be completely pacifist according to SN 35.88, MN 20, MN 86, MN 21.

"Well then, Punna. Now that I have instructed you with a brief
instruction, in which country are you going to live?"
"Lord, there is a country called Sunaparanta. I am going to live
there."
"Punna, the Sunaparanta people are fierce. They are rough. If they
insult and ridicule you, what will you think?"
"If they insult and ridicule me, I will think, 'These Sunaparanta
people are civilized, very civilized, in that they don't hit me with
their hands.' That is what I will think, O Blessed One. That is what I
will think, O One Well-gone."
"But if they hit you with their hands, what will you think?"
"...I will think, 'These Sunaparanta people are civilized, very
civilized, in that they don't hit me with a clod.'..."
"But if they hit you with a clod...?"
"...I will think, 'These Sunaparanta people are civilized, very
civilized, in that they don't hit me with a stick.'..."
"But if they hit you with a stick...?"
"...I will think, 'These Sunaparanta people are civilized, very
civilized, in that they don't hit me with a knife.'..."
"But if they hit you with a knife...?"
"...I will think, 'These Sunaparanta people are civilized, very
civilized, in that they don't take my life with a sharp knife.'..."
"But if they take your life with a sharp knife...?"
"If they take my life with a sharp knife, I will think, 'There are
disciples of the Blessed One who — horrified, humiliated, and
disgusted by the body and by life — have sought for an assassin, but
here I have met my assassin without searching for him.'  That is what
I will think, O Blessed One. That is what I will think, O One
Well-gone."
"Good, Punna, very good. Possessing such calm and self-control you are
fit to dwell among the Sunaparantans. Now it is time to do as you see
fit."
SN 35.88


A lay person can do whatever he or she deems right and if he is a Buddhist then he should at least be clear who is defending if he joins army. Defending Buddha is righteous thing to do as a Buddhist lay person. But as a staunch buddhist you should not even kill a mosquito if it bites you.

From my very first studies of Buddhism I found that "right livelihood" also meant "non involvement in war"
Joining the army at any capacity is in itself "wrong" livelihood.

Is there a sutta to support this answer? Thanks

From a quick internet search: Monks, these five trades ought not to be plied by a lay-disciple... Trade in weapons, trade
in human beings, trade in flesh, trade in spirits [intoxicants] and trade in poison. AN 5.177

My first understanding of right livelihood was signified as (also called non involvement in war)  Being a part of the war machine is "trading in weapons", trading in death, misery, suffering etc.  One who is wise would not do such things. A correct livelihood would be one that causes no harm to other beings while also benefits other beings. Though even this is complex as farming kills and harms beings. Even eating or breathing kills and harms beings. Most important thing is the intention.

Ideas of defending the defenceless, protecting weak & defending one's country are often delusions. For example:

There was a recent civil war in Sri Lanka, which was reported to have occurred due to Singhalese persecution of Tamils. In this situation, after Independence from Great Britain, the Singhalese held political power yet appeared to not act in the nature of a Buddhist Universal Monarch. The idea the Singhalese were "militarily defending their country" sounds spurious when they could have initially defended their realm of power simply with Dhamma (by not persecuting & provoking Tamils, with access to weapons from India & elsewhere).

There was never a nation named 'Ukraine' until it was created politically by the Russian Soviet Union in the 20th century. Also, much of the infrastructure of Ukraine was built by Russia. When certain Ukrainians sought to adversarially align Ukraine with The West & NATO rather than maintain neutrality, this was contrary to the Dhamma (that is, a lack of gratitude). The idea the Ukrainians are "militarily defending their country" sounds spurious when they could have simply initially defended their gifted nation with Dhamma (by not being ungrateful towards Russia).

For many centuries, the Muslim Empires were like Universal Monarchs. Many different cultures & religions, such as Muslims, Jews & Christians, lived in these Muslims Empires. When European Jews came to live in Palestine in the 1800s (even though many many more non-European Jews already lived near Palestine, such as in Egypt, Syria & Lebanon), they were generally welcomed & assisted by the various Palestinian peoples. However, over time, the Palestinian peoples were persecuted, such as the Gaza blockade, which the United Nations & other humanitarian organisations called the world's largest open-air prison. The idea of an Occupier defending their country against an Occupied Territory is contrary to International Law.


DN 26 says a Universal Monarch has troops to protect their realm. The realm of a Universal Monarch, similar to the Roman or Islamic Empires, is inclusive or pluralistic. Those with power should be benevolent rather than nationalistic. Those in receipt of benefaction should be grateful. The Tao Te Ching says:

SIXTY-ONE A great country is like low land. It is the meeting ground
of the universe, The mother of the universe. The female overcomes the
male with stillness, Lying low in stillness. Therefore if a great
country gives way to a smaller country, It will conquer the smaller
country. And if a small country submits to a great country, It can
conquer the great country. Therefore those who would conquer must
yield, And those who conquer do so because they yield. A great nation
needs more people; A small country needs to serve. Each gets what it
wants. It is fitting for a great nation to yield.

In summary, we should be careful & circumspect if attempting to define our personal war as "morally righteous" because the consequences can be very severe.
